# hello im try to run my flutter app on my real android phone but give me a lot of errors

Tags: flutter

Launching lib\main.dart on STK L21 in debug mode...
Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'...

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  A problem occurred configuring root project 'android'.

> Could not resolve all artifacts for configuration ':classpath'.
> Could not resolve com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.1.0.
> Required by:
> project :
> > Could not resolve com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.1.0.
> > Could not get resource 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/tools/build/gradle/4.1.0/gradle-4.1.0.pom'.
> > Could not GET 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/tools/build/gradle/4.1.0/gradle-4.1.0.pom'. Received status code 403 from server: Forbidden
> Could not resolve org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:1.3.50.
> Required by:
> project :
> > Could not resolve org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:1.3.50.
> > Could not get resource 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/org/jetbrains/kotlin/kotlin-gradle-plugin/1.3.50/kotlin-gradle-plugin-1.3.50.pom'.
> > Could not GET 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/org/jetbrains/kotlin/kotlin-gradle-plugin/1.3.50/kotlin-gradle-plugin-1.3.50.pom'. Received status code 403 from server: Forbidden

- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 1m 5s
Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1

Comment: update your Gradle version, target version and compiler version

Answer (score 1):

**How to Solve Flutter problems: “Could not resolve all artifacts for configuration ':classpath' ” Error?**
**To Solve Flutter problems:** “Could not resolve all artifacts for configuration ':classpath' ” this problem is caused by updating the Gradle. The Android Studio always asks you to update it, but don't do this for flutter apps. I solved it with the following versions On build.gradle module level.

**Flutter problems: “Could not resolve all artifacts for configuration ':classpath' ” Error**
**To Solve Flutter problems:** “Could not resolve all artifacts for configuration ':classpath' ” this problem is caused by updating the Gradle. The Android Studio always asks you to update it, but don't do this for flutter apps. I solved it with the following versions On build.gradle module level
**please follow this link** :https://fluttercorner.com/flutter-problems-could-not-resolve-all-artifacts-for-configuration-classpath/

Answer (score 0):

- 

First  You  run  Flutter Doctor

Comment: i do it but same problem